# Problem with decode UTF character from JSON data

Tags: json, utf

I post data from user and then convert to JSON data and store in database.
To avoid problem with escape char, I used

```
$jsonData = json_encode($array_json_data,JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

and it converted escaped char to UXXXX char.

Now I am having problem while decoding these data.

For example how can I print quote from U0027.

Answer (score 0):

use html_entity_decode  to convert quotes to its actual string representation

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.